# Is it possible to configure ConcurrentMap-based cache in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

The default implementation of the cache for Spring is a ConcurrentMap.
Using the default cache type, is it possible to configure a maximum size to avoid memory outages?
Are possible other kind of configurations for the ConcurrentMap-based cache in Spring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concurrent Map with fixed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758425/concurrent-map-with-fixed-size)

Comment: If I were you, I'll reconsider using ConcurrentMap as cache solution for memory reasons. Redis is a very good option for this kind of usage

Comment: you can use  `ConcurrentMap` create a `Cache` instance.

Answer (score 1):

The default cache type in Spring is suitable only for test and not for production. I suppose that your choice to do not looking for a more appropriate cache like Redis is due to for your use case a local cache is fine. If it is so I can suggest you to try caffeine, that support many parameters and with spring boot the configuration is very simple. The code below is taken from teh official spring boot configuration

```
spring.cache.cache-names=cache1,cache2
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=maximumSize=500,expireAfterAccess=600s
```

I hope that this can help you

Comment: I guess is not possible to easily configure the default cache. Indeed I'm looking for a local cache, that's why I discarded Redis. This could be a valid solution! Thanks!